# Pasting Copied Xpath from Ranorex Selocity Chrome Extension Not Working

Tags: xpath, ranorex

All of a sudden, whenever I click Selector actions -> copy xpath, and then try to paste that copied xpath, the xpath is not pasted. It's almost as if the xpath is not getting copied into my clipboard. This is while using the Ranorex Selocity Chrome extension. Any ideas? Below is a picture of what I am clicking on an example website. Thanks! [image]

Comment: Show us the code you are using to extract the copied XPath string somehow and see it's value

Comment: I'm not using code to extract the xpath, I'm just using Ranorex Selocity's built-in "Copy xpath" button and then pasting it into my code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Just click inspect and Ranorex Selocity should be one of the last tabs on the right. Click it and then you can copy the xpath that way. This doesn't really answer the question but it is a workaround that works. This a picture of what the process looks like: [image]